# Spring 3.1.x and java 7u80

Tags: spring, java-7

When compiled with java 7u79, spring 3.1 app is all good. When compiled on java 7u80, we're encountering some injection issues.

Searching a solution i found that Spring 3 is not compatible with java8, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22730801/java-se-spring-data-hibernate/30204461#30204461) (due to asm).

We can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30296000/why-does-java-8-apply-annotations-differently-to-derived-classes/30296846#30296846) that javac modifications were backported to java 7u80 and java 7u85.

So, am I rigth to think that it's same compatibility problem than for java 8, and that spring 3 app will not work if compiled on java7u80 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing my experience - yes, some spring versions have problems with java 8. For example in my project we've had to change spring from 3.2.4 to 3.2.9 to use java 8. I won't put here any particular example because I don't have one but I would advice you to give spring 3.2.9 a chance. We're using it successfully with Java 8.

Comment: This is not answering my question.
I'm not trying to make spring 3 app compatible with java 8, but jsute keeping it working on last java 7.

Comment: So I would advice to try different spring version because it is highly probable that the problem has been solved

Comment: You haven't clarified your problem as well - only mentioned some problem with compatibility. Please write whole stack trace here

Comment: Well I was just asking confirmation on what I thougth...
"So, am I rigth to think that it's same compatibility problem than for java 8, and that spring 3 app will not work if compiled on java7u80 ?"

Not asking any advise or solution. Just want to know if i'm the only one having troubles.

Comment: So,  yes,  we did have problems :)