# Java 8 method getAnnotation

Tags: java, java-8

I found Java 8 has a different from Java 7 on `Method.getAnnotation(Class<T> annotationClass)`,for example code:

```
public class Java8Test extends A<String> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<Java8Test> b = Java8Test.class;
        Method[] methods = b.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            Annotation annotation = method.getAnnotation(Resource.class);
            if (annotation != null) {
                System.out.println(method);
            }
        }
    }

    @Resource
    public void print(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
class A<T extends Object> {
    void print(T t) {
    }
}
```

Run with Java 8 print:

```
public void com.test.java8.Java8Test.print(java.lang.Object)
public void com.test.java8.Java8Test.print(java.lang.String)
```

Run with Java 6 or Java 7 print :

```
public void com.test.java8.Java8Test.print(java.lang.String)
```

How I got the real method .

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How to get the real method.

Comment: What do you mean the _real method_??

Comment: The method with a real annotation  @Resource .

Comment: I can not reproduce this with `JRE 1.8.0_60`. I only get `public void Java8Test.print(java.lang.String)` as output.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this with `JDK 1.8.0_65`.

Comment: I'm getting only one row, the one with the String. What version of Java 8 are you using? (Mine is 1.8.0_66)

Comment: weird I just get public void Java8Test.print(java.lang.String) with Java8

Comment: java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: @Magina Works as expected on 8u51: http://ideone.com/YBF83e - are you sure you are running the code you have shown?

Comment: @assylias http://ideone.com/0rTGNR look this.

Comment: You've found a [synthetic bridge](http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.de/2010/03/java-bridge-methods-explained.html) method afaik.

Comment: http://ideone.com/d4vYyc see line 23…

Comment: @Magina Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30296000/why-does-java-8-apply-annotations-differently-to-derived-classes